# Изучаю язык C. Не понимаю сути применение указателей

Tags: c

Цель была **создать структуру, записать в нее числа из файла в порядке убывания, и добавить пару чисел с клавиатуры и вывести в стандартный поток вывода**.

На одном из форумов нашел довольно емкий и компактный способ, но не совсем понимаю что там происходит (речь едет о функции Push).

Если кто-то сможет объяснить что происходит в ней,роль переменных именно в этой функции, был бы очень благодарен.

Знаю конечно, что разбираться в чужом коде не самое приятное занятие, так что уж простите(

**Ссылка на оригинал:** http://www.cyberforum.ru/c-linux/thread1009675.html

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _TNode
{
    double value;
    struct _TNode* next;
}   TNode;

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
TNode* Push(TNode** list, double value)
{
    TNode** tmp = list;
    TNode* node = malloc(sizeof(TNode));
    node->value = value;

    while ( *tmp && ((*tmp)->value > value) ) 
    {
        tmp = &(*tmp)->next ;
    }
    if (*tmp)
    {
        node->next = *tmp;
    }
    *tmp = node;

    return *list;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void Print(const TNode* list)
{
    while (list) 
    {    
        printf("%.1lf ", list->value);
        list = list->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE* f = stdin;
    TNode* list = NULL;
    double value;

    if (argc > 1)
    {
        if ((f = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL)
        {
            perror(argv[1]);
            return 9999;
        }
    }

    while ((fscanf(f, "%lf", &value)) == 1)
    {
        Push(&list, value);
    }

    while ((scanf("%lf", &value)) == 1)
    {
        Push(&list, value);
    }

    Print(list);

    return 1111;
}
```

Comment: `Push()` добавляет новый элемент к упорядоченному по убыванию списку чисел. Кстати, там есть ошибка (видимо она не проявлялась при тестировании автором, поскольку он всегда получал свежую память), после malloc поле next полученной структуры нужно обнулять.

Comment: С переменными в ней попробуйте сами разобраться с карандашом и бумагой, выдумайте адреса, которые выдает malloc (и вперед -))

Comment: *На одном из форумов нашел довольно емкий и компактный способ, но не совсем понимаю что там происходит* - реализуйте это все сами, а то так и не поймете